# Check a checkbox in parent when the field of child is true

Tags: trigger, roll-up-summary

I have a field in Opportunity material which is a related list in opportunity object.That field in opportunity material is a formula field that return value true or false.
I need to check a checkbox in opportunity when the field of opportunity material value is true. how can i achieve it

Comment: There can be multiple child Opportunity Material for a given opportunity, you want a field on opportunity to be true when any of childmaterial field is true?

Comment: Yes exactly if any one of the childmaterial field is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create a rollup summary field on Opportunity, called as Valid_Opportunity_Material_Count. You can add filter condition to rollup to count only if a certain field in opportunity Material is true.

[image]

2. Then you can create a new formulafield of type checkbox, it will only be true if the count in step 1 is greater than 0.

Comment: The field of Opprtunity material is a formula field so that i cant get the field in the roll up summary

Comment: You should edit your question and put that there, .. It is very critical piece of information

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: I quickly added a formula field on child and still was able to pull that value in rollup, can you try? @Swathi